# qbfc/qbxml ReceivePaymentAdd assign Payment to Invoice

Tags: sdk, quickbooks, qbxml, qbfc

When I try to associate a Payment with an Invoice, I get the following error:

```
ReceivePaymentAdd
ORApplyPayment:
OR object has multiple values
End of ORApplyPayment
End of ReceivePaymentAdd
```

What does that error mean? How do I get this to work?

Note that I am pushing the Invoice into QuickBooks in a separate session, so I cannot use Macros. If I use IsAutoApply true without the AppliedToTxnAdd block, the payment pushes just fine.

Here is the generated xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<?qbxml version="10.0"?>
<QBXML>
<QBXMLMsgsRq onError = "continueOnError">
<ReceivePaymentAddRq requestID = "0">
<ReceivePaymentAdd>
<CustomerRef>
<ListID>8000003F-1415364262</ListID>
</CustomerRef>
<ARAccountRef>
<FullName>Accounts Receivable</FullName>
</ARAccountRef>
<TxnDate>2014-02-14</TxnDate>
<RefNumber>1003 - P1</RefNumber>
<TotalAmount>850.00</TotalAmount>
<PaymentMethodRef>
<FullName>20 - Check</FullName>
</PaymentMethodRef>
<Memo/>
<IsAutoApply>0</IsAutoApply>
<AppliedToTxnAdd>
<TxnID>C7-1415364350</TxnID>
<PaymentAmount>850.00</PaymentAmount>
</AppliedToTxnAdd>
</ReceivePaymentAdd>
</ReceivePaymentAddRq>
</QBXMLMsgsRq>
</QBXML>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This:

> ORApplyPayment:
>   OR object has multiple values
>   End of ORApplyPayment

Means that the specification (see the QuickBooks OSR) specifies that you can use EITHER *AppliedToTxnAdd* OR you can use *IsAutoApply*, but you *may not use both of them*. You can use one, OR the other.

You're using *both*, so you're getting an error message. Either remove `<IsAutoApply>` or remove your `<AppliedToTxnAdd>` tag.

Here's an example for you:

- http://consolibyte.com/wiki/doku.php/quickbooks_qbxml_receivepaymentadd
- http://consolibyte.com/wiki/doku.php/quickbooks

Comment: Thanks so much! That error message is quite unclear, and I see nothing in the OSR about IsAutoApply being exclusive of AppliedToTxnId. It is all working now.

Comment: while I'm sure this answer is correct, I'm not so sure that's what the OR stands for. If I am correct, that wording in the answer can be misleading. I am basing my suspicion on this link: [developer-static.intuit](https://developer-static.intuit.com/qbsdk-current/samples/readme.html#billadd (C++) (qbfc) (desktop))

Comment: the previous link states: Setting an OR object (object of mutually exclusive elements) - Setting a Ref object (reference to another list object)

Comment: stackoverflow broke my link.. heres the correct link shortened: goo.gl/i7hnWb

Comment: I'm also trying to add ReceivePayment for a Invoice.  It will be really helpfull if someone answer for my doubt here.  Which '<TxnID>C7-1415364350</TxnID>
' number is added here in<AppliedToTxnAdd>. Is it that particular invoice 'TxnID' that we are going to generate for ReceivePayment?. Also how to add check number in payment type?

Comment: The `TxnID` is the `TxnID` of the _invoice_ you are applying a payment against.